# ggplot2: NA values not disconnecting lines when stacking them

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x=rep(1:5, 2), y=1:10, f=gl(2, 5, labels = letters[1:2])) 
df$y[df$x==3] <- NA
df
#    x  y f
# 1  1  1 a
# 2  2  2 a
# 3  3 NA a
# 4  4  4 a
# 5  5  5 a
# 6  1  6 b
# 7  2  7 b
# 8  3 NA b
# 9  4  9 b
# 10 5 10 b
```

I get this figure using ggplot2's default `position_identity` in `geom_line`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, color=f)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point(size=5)
```

[image]

And I get this figure when using `position_stack`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, color=f)) + 
  geom_line(position="stack") + 
  geom_point(size=5, position="stack")
```

[image]

Question: How do I indicate the `NA` values when using `position_stack`, i.e. how do I get the "hole" in the 2nd example?

My `packageVersion("ggplot2")` is `2.1.0`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an explicit `group` variable...?

```
df$grp <- c(1,1,NA,2,2,3,3,NA,4,4)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, color=f, group = grp)) + 
    geom_line(position="stack") +   
    geom_point(size=5, position="stack")
```

When I do that, I get this:

[image]

Comment: Nice, thanks. I tried `group=f`, but that did not work.